# How to append class on selected div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to append the check mark icon on selected div? I will provide my code. In this situation, I append checkmark icon only on first div.
Code pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VorBXJ

```js
function handleMyButtonClick(e) {
  console.log(e)
  document.getElementById("check-icon").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.second-column-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 50px;
}

#check-icon {
  display: none;
  background-image: url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-messaging-ui-color/254000/36-512.png)!important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat!important;
  background-position: center right!important;
  background-size: 60px 60px!important;
  max-width: unset!important;
  min-height: unset!important;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  cursor: pointer;
  right: 10%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="select-css" style="display: none;">1</div>
  <div onclick="handleMyButtonClick(event.target)" class="select-css" style="position: relative;">Kätzi
    <div id="check-icon"></div>
  </div>
  <div onclick="handleMyButtonClick(event.target)" class="select-css" style="position: relative;">Mausi
    <div id="check-icon"></div>
  </div>
  <div onclick="handleMyButtonClick(event.target)" class="select-css" style="position: relative;">Furioso
    <div id="check-icon"></div>
  </div>
  <div onclick="handleMyButtonClick(event.target)" class="select-css" style="position: relative;">Schattling
    <div id="check-icon"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: [Always use the validator](https://validator.w3.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the `id` attribute multiple times. ID's have to be unique. `getElementById` will get the first and only the first id since it assumes this invariant.

I'd recommend that you use a class (`.check-icon`), and use `querySelector` on the target to find the checkmark child:

```js
function handleMyButtonClick(e) {
  for (let element of document.querySelectorAll(".check-icon")) {
    element.style.display = "none";
  }
  e.querySelector(".check-icon").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.second-column-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 50px;
}

.check-icon {
  display: none;
  background-image: url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-messaging-ui-color/254000/36-512.png)!important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat!important;
  background-position: center right!important;
  background-size: 60px 60px!important;
  max-width: unset!important;
  min-height: unset!important;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  cursor: pointer;
  right: 10%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="select-css" style="display: none;">1</div>
  <div onclick="handleMyButtonClick(event.target)" class="select-css" style="position: relative;">Kätzi
    <div class="check-icon"></div>
  </div>
  <div onclick="handleMyButtonClick(event.target)" class="select-css" style="position: relative;">Mausi
    <div class="check-icon"></div>
  </div>
  <div onclick="handleMyButtonClick(event.target)" class="select-css" style="position: relative;">Furioso
    <div class="check-icon"></div>
  </div>
  <div onclick="handleMyButtonClick(event.target)" class="select-css" style="position: relative;">Schattling
    <div class="check-icon"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: When I use your code now every field is selected. Probably any class in my other code blocking display: none. One more question. How to forbidden multy select. Only one select is possible?!

Comment: Sorry Alex, but I simply do not understand your question

Comment: How to can the check only one question?

Comment: @Philip In this situation i can check few answear. I want to can check only one?

Comment: So you want only a single checkmark to be displayed at a time? If that's the case you can loop through all `.check-icon` and set their display to `none` and then the single `.check-icon` you want to `block`.

Comment: How I can do that? I am little confused

Comment: I've added some code to my answer (in the `handleMyButtonClick` function). Note that I'm using the `for ... of` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier/better to write a function that assigns an event listener to every div that needs to be clickable. In this function, the logic to add a checkbox to the 'selected' one is added.

The function will look something like this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.select-css').forEach(div => div.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.target.querySelector('.check-icon').style.display = 'block';
}));
```

```css
.second-column-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 50px;
}

.check-icon {
  display: none;
  background-image: url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-messaging-ui-color/254000/36-512.png) !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  background-position: center right !important;
  background-size: 60px 60px !important;
  max-width: unset !important;
  min-height: unset !important;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  cursor: pointer;
  right: 10%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="select-css" style="display: none;">1</div>
  <div class="select-css" style="position: relative;">Kätzi
    <div class="check-icon"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="select-css" style="position: relative;">Mausi
    <div class="check-icon"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="select-css" style="position: relative;">Furioso
    <div class="check-icon"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="select-css" style="position: relative;">Schattling
    <div class="check-icon"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How to can the check only one question?

Comment: In this situation i can check few answear. I want to can check only one?